# How to load a RDLC and Excecute it in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, rdlc

I'm trying to learn how these reports work and one thing I can't seem to figure out is how to create a basic application that would load an RDLC file, accept parameters for dataset, database connection string etc then export the RDLC as excel. Seems simple enough but I've racked my brain and scoured the web to figure it out.

What I'm trying to do:

C# console application

```
ReportExectute.exe -report Report1.rdlc -Dataset Dataset1.xsd -Connectionstring ConnectionString.txt
```

`ConnectionString.txt` would contain the connectionstring example:

```
Data Source=mediabeast;Initial Catalog=ReportServer;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=Password
```

Can anyone give pointers for the flow that I need to use?

Comment: Have a look at the example on this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.localreport.aspx

Answer (score 0):

if someone comes here - 
This is how you have to set your data from DB to report -

```
  viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("dataset_name_as_in_rdlc_file", dataset.Tables[0]));
```

Here the name "dataset_name_as_in_rdlc_file" should be same as in the rdlc file you use.and dataset.Tables[0] is the dataset you get from your query.

Answer (score 0):

When I started using rdlc I found a lot of usefull info on http://gotreportviewer.com/:

I recommended reading these links before starts using rdlc:

- [data sources](http://gotreportviewer.com/definedata/index.html)
- [report parameters](http://gotreportviewer.com/localmodeparameters/index.html)
- [master detail](http://gotreportviewer.com/masterdetail/index.html)
- [subreports](http://gotreportviewer.com/subreports/index.html)